# React Native Graphic Library for Windows?

Tags: reactjs, windows, graphics, components, native

I plan to develop cross-platform app that includes android, IOS, and windows.
I'm researching react-native, and I found that there is very small resource for windows OS.

Almost component libraries do not support windows, so I wonder if it's good idea that I implement app for cross-platform by RN.

component library, I only found 'fluent UI' by MS. it doesn't support android.
graph library, I have not found any.

is there more library that can be used for RN for windows? or RN is not the answer?

Comment: Me also searching!! Any update?